# find lpClassName of started application to be used in FindWindow wniapi c++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How can i find the lpClassName string of the FindWindow API call 
if i start application with CreateProcess API function

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo; //This is what we get as an [out] parameter

STARTUPINFO StartupInfo; //This is an [in] parameter

ZeroMemory(&StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo));
StartupInfo.cb = sizeof StartupInfo ; //Only compulsory field

if(CreateProcess("c:\\temp\\application1.exe", NULL,
NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,
NULL,&StartupInfo,&ProcessInfo))
{
WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
}
else
{
MessageBox("The process could not be started...");
}
```

also can i some how set only part of the name in the FindWindow ?
for example if i know that allays the app name is "application< some version number>.exe"
so it can be :
application1.exe
application1.1.exe
application1.2.1.exe

my final goal is to use Windows Message system and the SendMessage API method to send messages to the application.

Comment: This is impossible, use `EnumWindows` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to find the process window(s). Don't forget also to call `WaitForInputIdle` before starting to search for process windows.

Comment: do you know example that combine those functions ?
please see i updated the question

Comment: Take a look also at `GetClassName` API. Your question is not clear - there is no class name that belongs to application. What exactly you want to do?

Comment: The Quetion is simple 
start process, get its lpClassName , i need it to the FindWindow function .

Comment: Process does not have class name! What is your final goal? If you want to find all windows that process created, read again my first post.

Comment: Hey updated the question i want to use SendMessage in the end to operate the application.exe from my app

Comment: @user63898 Do you mind if I edit your question to be more clear about what you're asking for?

Comment: Not at all @Rick Yorgason

Comment: @user63898 Well, my edit was denied, but you can see what I was going to post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2256353). In particular, I think the title is much better at explaining your problem. Around here, explaining the problem with your solution rather than the actual problem you're trying to solve is called an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @user63898: if you enumerate the spawned process's windows like Alex or Hans suggests, then you will not need `FindWindow()` anymore, as you will have already found the `HWND(s)` you are looking for. On the other hand, it is unlikely that an app customizes its window class names based on version numbers, so you might just use Spy++ or similar tool to look at the actual class names used while the intended app is running, and then hard-code the values into your `FindWindow()` calls without having to hunt for them at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you *really* want is the handle to the window created by your launched application.

The problem is, your process might create *many* windows. You can use the [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to be notified whenever the process creates a new window.

Untested code incoming:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode,  WPARAM wParam,  LPARAM lParam) {
    if(nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND) {
        // wParam is a handle to a window your app just created.
    }
    return 0;
}

CreateProcess("c:\\temp\\application1.exe", NULL,
    NULL,NULL,FALSE,CREATE_SUSPENDED,NULL,
    NULL,&StartupInfo,&ProcessInfo);

SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, procHook, NULL, ProcessInfo.hThread);

ResumeThread(ProcessInfo.hTread);
```

Comment: The last parameter of `SetWindowsHookEx()` is a thread **ID**, not a thread **handle**. And in order to hook another process, the hook callback **must** reside in a DLL so it can be injected into the other process.